# Check if a word is in a text file

Tags: java

So, I have a program that is supposed to go through a file called dictionary.txt and check if the inputted word is inside the dictionary text file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args){

    String word = null;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    word = scan.nextLine();

    try {
        if(isInDictionary(word, new Scanner(new File("dictionary.txt")))){
            System.out.println(word + " is in the dictionary");
        } else System.out.println(word + " is NOT in the dictionary");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static boolean isInDictionary(String word, Scanner dictionary){

    List<String> dictionaryList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; dictionary.hasNextLine() != false; i++){
        ++i;
        dictionaryList.add(dictionary.nextLine());
        if(dictionaryList.get(i) == word){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}

}
```

When I try to run it I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at io.github.mediocrelogic.checkDictionary.Main.isInDictionary(Main.java:34)
at io.github.mediocrelogic.checkDictionary.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

Why am I receiving an IndexOutOfBoundsException here? There are no syntactic errors with the code. The dictionary.txt file is about 19.95mb, is that why I am receiving this exception?

Comment: "There are no syntactic errors" The JVM says there is.

Comment: @aliteralmind Pedantic: The compiler would catch syntactic errors, not the JVM. :)

Comment: The JVM reported a run time error based on the bug in the code. OP is correct, the syntax of the code was not the root cause of this problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the stray `++i` in your loop, it should fix your issue.

```
for(int i = 0; dictionary.hasNextLine() != false; i++){
    //++i;  // <-- THIS SHOULD GO AWAY!
    dictionaryList.add(dictionary.nextLine());
    if(dictionaryList.get(i) == word){
        return true;
    }
}
```

You are already incrementing `i` in your `for` statement. By incrementing it again inside the loop, `i` goes past the end of the dictionary, and hence the exception.

By the way, please also see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java), as you will not want to use `==` to compare strings there.

Comment: Ah, so the dictionary list becomes twice as large then? Thanks!

Comment: @user3479380 No, it doesn't. But your index grows twice as fast as the dictionary, and so you are guaranteed to get an out-of-bounds exception when trying to access that index in the dictionary. I've removed that statement because it was meant to be explanatory but it seems it misled you.

Comment: @user3479380 You may wish to read the documentation for [`ArrayList.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)), which clearly explains what that exception means.

Answer (score 4):

Please remove the line of code `++i;` entirely. `i` is already incremented in the `for` loop.

Comment: Will do, forgot that little detail as it was originally a while loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; dictionary.hasNextLine() != false; i++){
    ++i;
```

After that code your counter increase twice but the Index of the ArrayList just increased by one after this

```
dictionaryList.add(dictionary.nextLine());
```

That means you always trying to get an item from the ArrayList With i that is equal to ArrayList Index+1

You should remove this ++i from you code and it's will work

Also you can get better way to search for word into txt file using Regex and matcher object

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

or Indexof for more quickness search

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/indexOf.html